# Common Mode Rejection Ratio vs Common Mode Voltage

Tags: voltage, common-mode, differential-amplifier

I'm currently comparing characteristics of some different amplifiers, specifically their CMRR, and I came across [this amplifier](http://www.biometricsltd.com/datalog.htm), which rather than listing an explicit CMRR, merely says:

Maximum Common Mode 1.2 V

As it is, I can't find a CMRR listed anywhere on the website, is this an equivalent statement for CMRR? If so, how would I calculate an equivalent CMRR from this seemingly uninformative statement? I've done a google search and a search on here for any information regarding expressing CMRR as a voltage, but so far no luck

Comment: Max common mode I suspect is them saying that differential inputs can be measured accurately in the presence of a + or - 1.2V common mode voltage that might be offsetting the measurement above or below 0V. A lot of instrumentation amps and op-amps call it the common mode input range - how far can you push both inputs from 0V and still get an accurate differential measurment.

Comment: If I remember, CMRR is limited to the rail voltage. One amp design feeds back the Common Mode to cancel itself at the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That parameter says nothing about the CMRR. All it is telling you is the maximum [common mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common-mode_signal) voltage (\$V_{comm}\$) the amplifier can handle while still meeting the other specifications.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg9sm1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$ V_{comm} = \frac{V_+ + V_-}{2}$$

Provided that \$V_{comm} < 1.2V\$ (and really, they probably mean \$-1.2V < V_{comm} < 1.2V\$) then the amplifier will function according to specifications. Ostensibly, this common mode signal is attenuated, but if the CMRR is unspecified, then we don't know by how much.